# Concept of using a certain formula

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

A train travels a distance of 960 km in 16 hrs. The rails are separated by distance 130 cm. The vertical component of earth's magnetic field is given. We have to find the retarding force on the train due to the magnetic field, if resistance leakage is 100 ohm.

In the solution, they have used the formula $F=ilB$, which I can't understand. This is the formula used for force due to one current carrying wire on another, but I can't comprehend why it has been used here.

Comment: Is the train carrying charge?

Comment: Actually this the second part of the question, the first part asked the average emf induced across the width. So yes it is carrying charge

Comment: Well, if you have an emf (i.e. a voltage), and you know the train's resistance, then you can find the current. Is the current being conducted through the whole body of the train, or is it just through one point?

Comment: I think we have to treat the train as a single wire of some resistance that is sliding with a velocity, like illustrated as a common example of motional  emf

Comment: Ok, well then, there you go. You have your justification for applying the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emf induced in the axle is given by $\mathcal E = Blv$ so the induced current in the circuit which has a resistance $R$ is $I = \dfrac{Blv}{R}$

If a current $I$ passes through a conductor in a magnetic field $B$ the conductor feels a force $F = BIl$
Lenz says that the direction of the induced current will be such as to  **opposes** the motion producing the induced current.

In this case the induced current is responsible for a force $F = BIl$ opposing the motion and this is your retarding force.

To show that in terms of power the law of conservation of energy is not violated:

Power dissipated as heat in the electrical circuit is $I^2 R = \left ( \dfrac{Blv}{R}\right)^2 \, R = \dfrac {B^2l^2v^2}{R}$

The rate at which the retarding force is doing work is $F\, v = BIl \, v = B\left ( \dfrac{Blv}{R}\right ) l v= \dfrac {B^2l^2v^2}{R}$

So the work done by the retarding force becomes heat in the electrical circuit.